# strophe failed to connect openfire by websocket

Tags: websocket, openfire, strophe

OF version:3.9.1, I can use pidgin to log on.

When using strophe.js, I tried BOSH first, but it fails, probably I didn't get apache settings right. Then I decide to try websockets, and this is my preferred option, however, I got the following error message:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://ikan.tk:7070/ws/server' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

then the status is "connecting" always.

Questions:

1. what's the URL for websocket? using http-bind port (7070), or the client port (5222)? Any path (like /ws/server) to be followed ?
2. I'm using OF 3.9.1 on windows, no plugin installed. Does OF 3.9.1 support WS by default, or I have to install some plugin, or there's some configuration items I need to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK,

1) The URL for websocket on OpenFire is `ws://of-server:7070/ws` with default configuration (see below).

2) You need to install the "**WebSockets Plugin**" plugin for OpenFire, then you can configure the path of the websocket ("**ws**" is default) in properties page under the "Server > WebSockets" tab.

Comment: Thanks! Have chosen Tigase, which support websocket as built-in.

Comment: there is no any WebSockets tab available, I am using openfire 4.0.1