# Strophe to Openfire: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

Tags: websocket, openfire, strophe

I am writing a simple chat client (using strophe) which connects to my Openfire server. Strophe works successfully with BOSH, but for some reason cannot connect using websockets.

I have installed the latest version (websockets-0.0.0.6) of "WebSockets Plugin" plugin for OpenFire, using the default path "ws". My client url is `ws://my-server:7070/ws`.

I get the following error in my browser console:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7070/ws' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

I look at other related post ([stackoverflow.com/questions/22983302/strophe-failed-to-connect-openfire-by-websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983302/strophe-failed-to-connect-openfire-by-websocket)) but have not been successful.

Has anyone come across this problem before?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see when going to **http**://my-server:7070/ws from browser address bar?

Comment: ... and **http**://my-server:7070/

Comment: For  http://my-server:7070/ws I see in the browser: Openfire HTTP Binding Service

Comment: For http://my-server:7070/ws I see the directory structure in the browser the following: Directory: /ws/

WEB-INF/  
changelog.html  
lib/
ofchat-010.crx  
peek/ 
plugin.xml 
readme.html  
sparkweb/  
web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you were using the latest version of Strophe. The openfire-websocket is developed against with older version Strophe 1.0 . They are not capable now.
You can take a look at https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/53783